# Cannot register C++/CLR .NET Project after moving from VS2008 to VS2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c++-cli, upgrade

I recently decided to upgrade to VS2010 from VS2008. One of my projects is a C++/CLR .NET dll. It is strong named and this caused a problem originally as there are some issues with this in VS2010. However, I believe I have resolved them. Anyway, when I try to register the debug dll I used:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe "C:\Project\AnalystIDA_plugin_PrecursorScan_OpenFileOnce_VCPP\Analyst_UserIDA\Debug\Analyst_UserIDA.dll" /tlb:Analyst_UserIDA.tlb /codebase
```

and get the generic error:

```
RegAsm : error RA0000 : Unable to locate input assembly 'C:\Project\AnalystIDA_plugin_PrecursorScan_OpenFileOnce_VCPP\Analyst_UserIDA\Debug\Analyst_UserIDA.dll' or one of its dependencies.
```

Using Dependency Walker I see a few dlls causing problems:

```
EFSADU.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL
WER.DLL
```

From what I have seen I have no idea why these dll would be required. Anyway, anyone have any idea why this might be occurring after conversion between the versions of VS?\

**Edit:**

I found that there is a well known bug in VS2010 that causes problems when trying to use strong names.
[Proposed workarounds for strong naming bug in VS2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/03/11/10140139.aspx)

Comment: Those are just the normal delay-loaded DLLs that DependencyWalker always complains about.  If you are sure that the DLL actually exists then troubleshoot with SysInternals' ProcMon utility.  You'll see Regasm searching for a DLL and not finding it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe "C:\Project\AnalystIDA_plugin_PrecursorScan_OpenFileOnce_VCPP\Analyst_UserIDA\Debug\Analyst_UserIDA.dll" /tlb:Analyst_UserIDA.tlb /codebase
```

?